# mod_rewrite different languages part of url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, get

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ /launcher/index.html [L]

RewriteRule ^en/admin$ /main/index.php?lang=en&action=acp [L]
RewriteRule ^sp/admin$ /main/index.php?lang=sp&action=acp [L]

RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /main/$1?lang=en [L]
RewriteRule ^sp/(.*)$ /main/$1?lang=sp [L]
```

I have a launcher screen (which is working fine), and my site PHP files which is main/index.php. I use $_GET to pass information about what page to my index.php ie: index.php?action=download&file=123. There are two root levels I'm going to use /en/ for english, and /sp/ for spanish. These are passed to index.php as ?lang=en or ?lang=sp.

I have 2 problems that I cannot fix;

- My rules have a strange inconsistency of failing. There's probably a better way of doing what I'm trying to do. I'd highly appreciate if someone can show me how. I'm a complete noob at mod_rewrite
- When I add more things to the end of the URL using a ?variable=value, it occurs after ?lang=en or ?lang=sp. This means that the second question mark causes $_GET to glitch, and those $_GET passed variables are lost. I need a way to append two $_GET together with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your second problem, have you looked into using the QSA flag? Quoting the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> 'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)
>
> This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

Regarding the first question, you can potentially combine the `en` and `sp` into a single rule like below. It is arguable whether this is an improvement, though.

```
RewriteRule ^(en|sp)/(.*)$ /main/$2?lang=$1 [L,Q]
```